# understanding store in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

I am new to `ExtJS` and I find documentation confusing, I need to get the first data from store, which I get from the report. How to do it correctly?

```
    this.divisionList = new ....SimplestReportCombo({        
            fieldLabel: "Division",
            allowBlank: false,
            valueField: 'KEY',
            displayField: store.load.get(0),
            width: 200,
            reportID: 'USER_ACCESS',
            store : new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                    fields: [{name: 'KEY'}],
                    data: [{name: 'VALUE'}]
                }
            )
        });
```

Comment: please add code written to develop stores

Answer (score 1):

Javascript Stores mostly resembles RDBMS tables. They have in memomy storage and they are helpful to perform various grid level operation like sorting , paging ,  shuffling , editing etc.

Lets come to your code now,

You dont need to load store get its elements.If you requirement is only to select 1st ellement from store then you can do that using **getAt** function like below:

```
 this.divisionList = new ....SimplestReportCombo({

    fieldLabel: "Division",
    allowBlank: false,
    valueField: 'KEY',
    displayField: store.getAt(0),
    width: 200,
    reportID: 'USER_ACCESS',
    store : new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: [{name: 'KEY'}],
            data: [{name: 'VALUE'}]
        }
    )
});
```

**or else** you can also use following store method if you want to render mere 1st element:

```
store.first()
```

Comment: i got an error - ReferenceError: store is not defined

Comment: :-D Should I define it?

Comment: how to define a store based on report?

Comment: Which extjs version you are using